# Python unit test failing even though the expectation match

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

I'm sure as of writing this there is something very basic I'm missing here...

I have following python function

```
## views.py

from flask import request, jsonify
log_obj = EdgeLogger(name='edge_api')

def notifyMobile(ip):
    r = requests.post(MobileToPortableMid.NOTIFY_MOBILE_URL, data=jsonify({"portable_mid_ip": ip}), headers=None)
    
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        log_obj.debug("ip address sent to mobile edge")
    else:
        log_obj.error("error sending ip address resulted in following status code: {}".format(r.status_code))
```

which I'm looking to test..

unittest for it look something like this.

```
  from unittest.mock import patch, call, Mock, MagicMock
  import json
  import unittest
  @patch('views.log_obj')
  @patch('requests.post')
  def test_notify_mobile(self, mock0, mock1):
    from views import notifyMobile
    from flask import jsonify
    mock1.debug = MagicMock(return_value=None)
    testapp = app
    with testapp.app_context():
      notifyMobile('127.0.0.1')
      mock0.assert_called_with("http://localhost:8080/portable_mid/connect", data=jsonify({"portable_mid_ip": "127.0.0.1"}), headers=None).return_value.status_code = 200
      mock1.debug.assert_called_with("ip address sent to mobile edge")
```

When I run the test case I see the expectation and actual result matched but the test case still fails

```
E           AssertionError: expected call not found.
E           Expected: post('http://localhost:8080/portable_mid/connect', data=<Response 32 bytes [200 OK]>, headers=None)
E           Actual: post('http://localhost:8080/portable_mid/connect', data=<Response 32 bytes [200 OK]>, headers=None)
```

I don't know enough python to understand what is reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `jsonify` with `json.dumps` and it worked.

```
      mock0.assert_called_with("http://localhost:8080/portable_mid/connect", data=json.dumps({"portable_mid_ip": "127.0.0.1"}), headers=None).return_value.status_code = 200
```